# problem with filter in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Build an application with MongoDB and NodeJS as backend-server. Fetched some `companies` details from database according to their `category id`, the problem is that the information is not displayed on both postman and ionic project, when called this API.

What to do to resolve this problem?

Sample code:

```
function filtrarPorCategoria(busqueda, regex) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Empresa.find({ categoria: busqueda }, 'nombre estado').exec((err, empresas) => {
            if (err) {
                reject('Error al cargar las empresas', err);
            } else {
                console.log(empresas);
                resolve(empresas);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[This is response over postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHcBF.png)

Comment: Does console.log prints anything? Also, we need to have a look at your sample mongo data for which query should be satisfying

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to wrap the whole thing with `Promise` since [exec gives you](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) a fully-fledged one already:

```
const getFn = (busqueda) =>
    Empresa.find({ categoria: busqueda }, 'nombre estado').exec()
      .then(empresas => console.log(empresas))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Also in your case specifically you are dealing with promise and you are not returning anything (should be `return Empresa.find(...`). In the code above we use ES6 implicit return.

Comment: You might have to add more context (pieces of your code). Like try `console.log(empresas)` right before the `if` and see what is in there etc.